# build an array of an array from SQL query with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following working array of an array in PHP:

```
$explore1 = array
(
array("a.html", "A"),
array("b.html", "B"),
array("c","C")
);        
$arrlength = count($explore1);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
  echo '<li><a href="'.$explore1[$x][0].'">'.$explore1[$x][1].'</a></li>';
}  }
```

I want to populate the explore1 array from SQL. If i simply change the code like below it has errors but I don't know what I'm suppose to do instead?

```
$sql = 'SELECT url, name FROM explore_items WHERE menuID="item1"';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $explore1 = array  //IT DOESN'T LIKE THIS LINE
(
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // BUILD SAME LINES AS ABOVE WITH ECHO
    echo "array('" . $row["url"]. ", '" . $row["name"]. "'),";
}
);
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: `$explore1 = []; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {$explore1[] = [$row["url"], $row["name"]];}`

Comment: While your attempt maybe failed, you still tried your best to solve the problem yourself and analysed the code a bit. And that's good + *try and error* is how you learn.

Answer (score 1):

Either you don't need `$explore1` at all:

```
$sql = 'SELECT url, name FROM explore_items WHERE menuID="item1"';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //echo "array('" . $row["url"]. ", '" . $row["name"]. "'),";
    echo '<li><a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
  }
}
```

or if you need you can `fetch_all()`:

```
$sql = 'SELECT url, name FROM explore_items WHERE menuID="item1"';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $explore1=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  foreach($explore1 as $row ) {
    //echo "array('" . $row["url"]. ", '" . $row["name"]. "'),";
    echo '<li><a href="'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a></li>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex I was coming to same conclusion that I didn't need $explore, new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn some php basics.
Defining an array of arrays is something like:

```
$explore1 = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $explore1[] = array($row["url"], $row["name"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @u_mulder looks perfect also. I'm aware this is probably basic to most but I learn by doing all the W3schools and google and I still couldn't work this out, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must populate the array inside the loop:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $explore1[$row["url"]] = $row["name"];
}
```